# Instance has no attribute error

Tags: python

```
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.suits = ['s', 'h', 'd', 'c']
        self.ranks = ['6' ,'7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
        self.deck = [i+j for i in self.ranks for j in self.suits]
        random.shuffle(self.deck)

    def selectCards(self):
        self.selectedCard = self.deck.pop()
        return self.selectedCard

    def respresentDeck(self, dck):
        symbols = { 'c': u"\u2663", 'h': u"\u2665", 's': u"\u2660", 'd': u"\u2666"}
        tempL = [x for sublist in dck for x in sublist]
        representList = [symbols[i] + '  ' if i in symbols else i for i in tempL]
        representList = list('Deck: ') + representList
        return u"".join(representList).encode('utf-8').strip()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.representDeck(self.deck)

class Game:
    newDeck = Deck()
    print(newDeck)
```

I am trying to represent card in ascii format but I get an error `return self.representDeck(self.deck)
AttributeError: Deck instance has no attribute 'representDeck'`

I have very similar code for `Player` class and it all works great but this does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled `represent`:

```
>>> Deck.respresentDeck.__name__ == 'representDeck'
False
```

That's because there is an `s` too many in it:

```
>>> print '\n'.join(['representDeck', Deck.respresentDeck.__name__])
representDeck
respresentDeck
# ^
```

Correct the name of the method:

```
def representDeck(self, dck):
    # ...
```

Comment: I was sure I checked it many times. Oh sorry for stupid question :/

Answer (score 1):

You spelt the word wrong in `__str__` method it does not match the method name:

```
self.respresentDeck(self.deck)
```

But it actually should be `representDeck` in your method as it is  the correct spelling of the word.

So `def representDeck(self, dck):` and `return self.representDeck(self.deck)`.